# Can i use mysql_real_escape_string inside the query?

Tags: php

Instead doing that:

```
$var1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['1']);

$sql="INSERT INTO vartable (var)
VALUES ('$var1')";
```

Can i do that?

```
$var1 = $_POST['1'];

$sql="INSERT INTO vartable (var)
VALUES ('mysql_real_escape_string($var1)')";
```

It works write?

Comment: You'd be better switching to MySQLi or PDO and learning to use prepared statements with bind variables rather than learning the old, deprecated MySQL extension

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use it like

```
$sql="INSERT INTO vartable (var)
VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($var1)."')";
```

NOTE: `mysql_*` is Deprecated user `mysqli_*` or `PDO`